# SaaS DNS settings

Tags: dns, multi-tenant, saas

I run a small e-commerce platform, and over the past two years have grown customers.

There's around 100 customers now and their domains point to our server IP by the use of two A records (@ and www).

I'm not experienced in this area so I need someone who's knowledgable about setting up major SaaS projects.

The worry I have is, if for whatever reason I change host, wouldn't I lose the IP address? And surely at that point, I may need to ask over 200 customers to change their DNS settings to point to our new server?

A friend said to me about using a CNAME (pointing to a domain I own), but another professional server contact told me that it's not ideal. What further confuses me is this:
If my point remains true (and that an IP isn't able to be owned), then how come [Squarespace](https://support.squarespace.com/hc/en-us/articles/205812378-Connecting-a-domain-to-your-Squarespace-site) and a few other major players have an option to instruct their users that they can use an A record to point to their (squarespace/wix..) IP address? Do they know something I don't (do they own an IP?)?  What happens if squarespace for whatever reason have to change IP, surely 100,000's+ customers would need to change their IP A records? This seems very impractical and not realistic. It really confuses me.

I'd really appreciate some enlightening in this area, because I need to know sooner rather than later if I dig myself into a hole if I get over 500 customers and for whatever reason I end up having to ask 500 of them to change DNS settings.

Thanks.